# Asynchronous coroutine handling in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have used a coroutine to do a backend service call to retrieve the player categories in my category.cs file:

```
public override void OnEnter(Page p)
    {
        backend = globalScriptObject.GetComponent<IBackendController>();
        items.Clear ();

        StartCoroutine (backend.GetPlayerProfile ( profile =>{

            this.maxSelectableItems = Mathf.CeilToInt(profile.level/10+1);
            if(this.maxSelectableItems == 7) maxSelectableItems = int.MaxValue;
            DisableSelections();
        }));
```

GetPlayerProfile (In a different class which has been called using instance backend of that class)

```
public IEnumerator GetPlayerProfile(System.Action<Profile> callback){
        yield return GetPlayerProfile (callback, false);
    }
```

Issue:

Since i am using an external service call,sometimes the player profile is uploaded with a delay.

I need to make sure that the startcoroutine is finished with result before the rest of the lines of code is executed.

I tried creating the following class after searching from the internet which can make sure the couroutine call is finished before the rest of the lines are executed:

```
    {
    StartCoroutine(FinishFirst(5.0f, DoLast));
     }

     IEnumerator FinishFirst(float waitTime, Action doLast) {
         print("in FinishFirst");
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
         print("leave FinishFirst");
         doLast();
     }


 void DoLast() {
     print("do after everything is finished");
     print("done");
 }
```

But how can i use the above in my source code is what i would need suggestions from the community.

Also can i do something like yield return waitForSec(Float) in the GetPlayerProfile method?

Thanks !!

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. The rest of your code (`DisableSelections();`) should work only when the FinishFirst function is done.

Comment: It sounds like [async - await](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/) might fit your needs better than Coroutines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply derHugo,I am using unity 3D to develop this gaming application.Unity generally recommends to use co routines and that's where the issue comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Try using WaitUntil.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html

Something like this:

```
IEnumerator GetProfile(){
    var profile = null;
    yield GetPlayerProfile((p) => {profile = p});
    yield WaitUntil(p != null);
    this.maxSelectableItems = Mathf.CeilToInt(profile.level/10+1);
    if(this.maxSelectableItems == 7) maxSelectableItems = int.MaxValue;
    DisableSelections();
}
```

And then...

```
StartCoroutine(GetProfile);
```